# android ble advertising packet example source please

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet, ads

I want to ble advertising to a specific receiver with android app.
I was told that I had to perceive using packets.
i don't understand
I need an example source with detailed explanation.
please.

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth/wiki/One-minute-to-understand-BLE-advertising-data-package

Comment: Example - [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothAdvertisements), 김재룡 try implementing something yourself, you got a problem, SO is always here :)